# More cells in TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a `tableview` that I am populating with `JSON`, but it is doubling the values that I have. I only have 2 objects, but it is putting 4 in the `tableview`. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and why I am listing 4 objects when there are only 2? I have checked the count and the data model and they both only show 2 items.

Here is my code:

```
    //
//  RootBeerTableViewController.m
//  BaseApp
//
//  Created by Blaine Anderson on 9/27/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 UIEvolution, Inc. All rights reserved.
//

#import "RootBeerTableViewController.h"
#import "GlobalData.h"

@interface RootBeerTableViewController ()



@end

@implementation RootBeerTableViewController

@synthesize rootList;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame] style:UITableViewStylePlain];

    tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    tableView.delegate = self;

    tableView.dataSource = self;

    [tableView reloadData];



    self.view = tableView;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    rootList =[[GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeers getRootBeers];
     NSLog(@"RootList: %@", rootList);
    // Return the number of sections.
    NSLog(@"RootList count: %i", rootList.count);
    return rootList.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
        // Return the number of sections.
     NSLog(@"RootList row count: %i", rootList.count);
    return rootList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    rootList =[[GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeers rootBeerList];
     NSLog(@"RootList Cell: %@", rootList);
    RootBeers* mRootBeer = [rootList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle  reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"]; 
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
    NSLog(@"Cell Name: %@", mRootBeer.name);
       // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = mRootBeer.name; 
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = mRootBeer.brewer; 



    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [[GlobalData sharedData].mViewManager pushView:DETAILVIEW animated:YES]; 



}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is why...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
rootList =[[GlobalData sharedData].mRootBeers getRootBeers];
 NSLog(@"RootList: %@", rootList);
// Return the number of sections.
NSLog(@"RootList count: %i", rootList.count);
return rootList.count;
}
```

change it to this.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
```

You are adding a section for each object in rootList, and then adding all of rootlist in each section. So returning only one section is easiest.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! Solved the problem!